# How to change the switch component's size in React Native?

Tags: react-native

How to change the switch component's size in React Native?

```
<Switch onValueChange={this._changeReciveNotice.bind(this)}
        value={this.state.isReciveNotice}
        style={{width:20,height:10}}/>
```

this style code doesn't effect

Answer (score 213, accepted):

You can resize the switch by using transform property from styling,

```
<Switch value={true}
style={{ transform: [{ scaleX: .8 }, { scaleY: .8 }] }}
onValueChange={(value) => {}} />
```

also for best result determine scaling values based on screen dimension.

Comment: Yes, had this issue myself and have been using this method to scale for all android and iOS devices.

Comment: For me size was fine for android but for ios it was too big size. This helped me. Thanks

Comment: A short hand for scaling both axis is {scale: .8}

Answer (score 11):

To expand on what was already said, this is how you can handle screen sizes:

```
import { moderateScale } from 'react-native-size-matters';

...

<Switch 
   style={{ transform: [{ scaleX:  moderateScale(1, 0.2) }, { scaleY:  
   moderateScale(1, 0.2) }] }} />
```

Answer (score 5):

If the size is a UI concern only you can add a negative margin

For example on my case i  would just reduce the height (a little) to keep things aligned:

```
<Switch style={{marginVertical: -8}} />
```

Answer (score -2):

```
        <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: this.state.value
          ? "rgba(81, 195, 157, 0.16)"
          : "rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.16)",
        borderRadius: 50,
        paddingVertical: 2,
        paddingHorizontal: 4
      }}
    >
      <Switch
        tintColor="transparent"
        thumbTintColor={this.state.value ? "#51c39d" : "#cccccc"}
        onTintColor="transparent"
        value={this.state.value}
        style={{ transform: [{ scaleX: 1.3 }, { scaleY: 1.3 }] }}
        onValueChange={value => this.setState({ value })}
      />
    </View>
```

Comment: It's just a way to customize the switch component.

Comment: That's not an explanation of the code. You should say how you're customizing the switch component to make a better answer. The other answers for this question can give you an example of how they explain their code.